# Config Resche schedule to delay sending mail in specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque, rufus-scheduler, resque-scheduler

**SO sorry if this is a duplicate, I tried searching for this but wasnt sure what search terms to use and didnt really find anything**

I'm currently research on how to set up a schedule of job-to-do when a server start on my application. The function I want to make is like sending a weekly/monthly mail to all the users. The problem is, if the quantity of the mail need to send is enormous, Which cant be send in just a few hours (I dont like to sent mail to users at the time of night); It will pause and continue this job in the next morning....

So far as I've searched, I found two gems: resque-scheduler and rufus-scheduler. I don't really know which one should I focus on digging on.

Can anyone point me out which general direction shout I go? Which one of those has built-in function can doing task like those ? Or I need to set up schedule on my own ?...

Answer (score 0):

Look at resque-scheduler (it uses rufus-scheduler and resque behind the scenes).